# How i can get probabilities in DeepPavlov classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, deeppavlov

I train my classifier using DeepPavlov, and then when i call trained model for some sample function returns only one class label, but I want to get the probabilities of every class. I did not find function parameters that would allow me to get probabilities.
Has anyone encountered such a problem? Thank!

```py
from deeppavlov import configs, train_model

model = train_model(configs.classifiers.intents_snips)

model(['Some sentence'])
```

I want the output like np.array with number of classes length, but current output is one label like ['PlayMusic'].

Comment: could oyu provide the set-up of the model? n_classes – number of considered classes e.g....

Comment: n_classes, for example in the question, is 7
Other model parameters are defined in configs.classifiers.intents_snips config file:
https://github.com/deepmipt/DeepPavlov/blob/master/deeppavlov/configs/classifiers/intents_snips.json

Answer (score 1):

You can change `chainer.out` parameter of your config to be `["y_pred_probas"]` before inferring, but it will also most likely require you to update change [`train.metrics`](http://docs.deeppavlov.ai/en/master/intro/configuration.html#metrics) if you want to train your model on the same config.

Alternatively you can call your model like

```py
model.compute(['Some sentence'], targets=["y_pred_probas"])
```

And to get classes indexes you can run

```py
dict(model['classes_vocab'])
```